# Java object oriented - data structures

Tags: java

I am working on a project in netbeans that creates a bank management system; the user will key-in their account number, name, address. This information will be stored in a class with unlimited storage size. I also want a function to print the last six transactions stored with the account.

The main problem I have come across is what type of data structure can I use to store an unlimited number of objects for both accounts, and transactions, and which will be me searchable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [java's collection framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'unlimited storage size'. Memory, heap, and disk are all finite.

Comment: Depending on the scope of the project a database may be appropriate. [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial on Vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html); maybe [an embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database)? Of course that would be a total overkill, if it's only a homework exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any built in class that implements the `List` interface (e.g. `LinkedList` or `ArrayList` can be used to store as much data as the JVM will allow your program to use. To store these after the program closes, you'll need a way to store the data in either a file or a database of some sort, which you can load into a List as needed. As the `List` interface includes the `contains(Object o)` method, any subclass can be searched.

See the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Should accounts and transaction be stored in one (arraylist) or can two arraylist be linked?

Comment: A List is parameterized with one class or interface (that's why you'd declare it as, say, `ArrayList<Account>`). If you're writing separate classes for accounts and transactions (you should), the Account class can contain a List of Transactions objects, while the main class can contain a List of Accounts. You'd then access the transactions through the Account object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
Queue - LIFO(Last in, First out): Printing last 6 transaction will be no problem.
ArrayList: very fast structure when adding new element, and if you know index of element it is also very fast with searching and deleting.
Or you can use some kind of Tree.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Should accounts and transaction be stored in one (arraylist) or can two arraylist be linked?

Comment: Account and transaction are two differenct object, that cannot be stored in one list. You must use two lists.